# insist on "Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop"

Tags: reactjs

I know what does it means and solved this problem many times with setting unique id to child items but this time it still throws the same exception and I couldn't understand why

here is the code;

```
    render() {
     question.Choices = this.appState.question.Choices.map((value, index) => {
            if (typeof value == "string")
              return (<SQcomponent index={index} value={question.Number + "-" + index} text={value} checkedHandler={this.choiceChecked} />)
    })
    return (<div> {question.Choices} </div>)
  }
}


    class SQcomponent extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
      }
      render() {
        return (<div key={this.props.index} className="checkbox checkbox-circle">
          <input id={this.props.index} name={this.props.index} type="checkbox" value={this.props.value} />
          <label htmlFor={this.props.index}>
            {this.props.text}
          </label>
        </div>)
      }
    }
```

when I start the application it works fine but this messege annoying me;
[image]

Comment: You need to set a key on `SQcomponent`. Rather you have set your key on the root element of `SQcomponent` render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the key on the component in your map:

```
    render() {
     question.Choices = this.appState.question.Choices.map((value, index) => {
            if (typeof value == "string")
              return (<SQcomponent key={index} index={index} value={question.Number + "-" + index} text={value} checkedHandler={this.choiceChecked} />)
    })
    return (<div> {question.Choices} </div>)
  }
}
```

Though, you should use a value other than *index* for your key.

> When you don't have stable IDs for rendered items, you may use the
>   item index as a key as a last resort:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html